# Why is SHA-3 robust against Length-Extension Attacks?

Tags: mac, sha-3

If a length extension attack can occur because of $H(\text{K}\mathbin\|\text{Message})$, what changed in SHA-3 from SHA-2 that prevents this from occurring?

Comment: SHA-3 is not an updated version of SHA-2; they are completely separate algorithms.

Answer (score 41):

*Everything* was changed between SHA-2 and SHA-3.

In the specific case of the "length extension attack": the issue is that SHA-2 process data by splitting it into elementary blocks (64 or 128 bytes, depending on the SHA-2 variant), and produces for each block an output which has exactly the same size as the function output. Moreover, the output for a complete message is merely the current output after processing all blocks of the (padded) message. This means that anybody can take a hash output and "continue" processing of a longer message with additional blocks.

In SHA-3, a [sponge construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sponge_function) is used. The crucial point is that, in a sponge, the internal state is much larger than the hash function output. Thus, you cannot simply "continue" processing of a message by using a hash output, because that output contains only a fraction of the internal state.

You can get the same kind of protection with a SHA-2 function by truncating the output. For instance, there is a (relatively new) member of the SHA-2 family called "SHA-512/256", which is SHA-512 (with a different conventional IV) with output truncated to 256 bits. This truncation makes it immune to the length extension attack.

Comment: Note that in the SHA-2 family, SHA-224 and SHA-384 have limited protection against length extension attacks. But they are not very safe, unlike SHA-3 which is designed to be resistant to length extension from the start.

Comment: I believe the main reason for introducing SHA-512/256 is that on 64 bit CPUs it is faster than SHA-256. But I'd usually go with SHA384 which is a bit more widely supported than SHA-512/256. The only two differences between SHA384 and SHA-512/256 is a different IV and being truncated to different lengths.

Comment: this sounds complete bogus to me - as I've understood it, the problem with SHA2 allowing length extension is that SHA2 on completion dumps it's entire internal state (with the exception of SHA2-224 and SHA2-384 which only dumps 50% of it's internal state) - SHA3 doesn't